# LM2678 DC-DC voltage regulator, output overvoltage

Tags: power, voltage

I tested the LM2678SX-5.0/NOPB integrated for use in PCB design. I expected a 5 volt fixed output, I got 7.4V.

You can see the regulator circuit I designed in the appendix. I set up the same circuit in the datasheet. Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: Are you measuring the output voltage with a load attached or under no-load conditions?

Comment: Check teh datasheet for "minimum load" recommendations (usually expressed as a current).

Comment: I measure with no-load. I measure 5V output with 1K resistor, but again I measure like 7.4V with 1M resistor.

Comment: That is normal. With no load (or too light a load) the output capacitors retain too much voltage. You need a load for the capacitors to drain into - otherwise it acts like a peak detector...

Comment: So, should I use it by connecting a resistor to the output, or will the source I connect to the output be enough as a load? I don't want the microprocessor to draw too much voltage and get damaged.

Comment: You need to fulfill the minimum load requirements. Add a zener diode or resistor. Alternatively, choose a better regulator.

Comment: The minimum load requirements are defined by the inductor / output capacitor combination. To run with lighter loads reduce the output capacitors. To run with heavier loads increase the output capacitors. If you are finding that the voltage is too high with your actual load attached then your capacitors are too big - however that is highly unlikely. If your load is really that light then why have a 5A switcher?

Comment: I am feeding Jetson Nano with this circuit. If I can't get a fixed 5 Volt output in this circuit, does it affect other things? For example, anomalies on the PCB when the relay circuits are operating.

Comment: If it were me and I decided to add a load I would use a LED, that solves two problems, is it on and will hold the voltage assuming it exceeds the minimum load requirement.